# Is there a way to edit a file or append data on it while its hidden with attrib?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to edit a file or append data on it while its hidden with attrib?

It has to be fast (thats why the second example is not usefull for me...)

Of cours an example ...

```
attrib +H file.txt
echo file > file.txt
```

This doesn`t work, I get access dinied.

Is there a way to do this? And this is not usefull for me -->

```
attrib +H file.txt
attrib -H file.txt
echo file > file.txt
attrib +H file.txt
```

Thnx!

Comment: According to your example you don't want to edit the file, you just want to append data onto it.  is that right?

Comment: yea sorry, I just do every time:  echo %var% > file.txt

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo file > file.txt
attrib +H file.txt
set var=abc
>file.tmp echo %var%
type file.tmp >> file.txt
del file.tmp
pause
```

Comment: I need something what is fast, this takes a lot of time I think. Is there an other way?

Comment: How do you define `fast`?  Without a full description nobody knows what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean something that is fast. Soo... Just in the batch file without making files. (thats faster i think)